# R2 scores when the output is a 2D value

Tags: mathematical-statistics, linear

Based on my readings, `R2` is used to calculate the closeness of fit for regression models where

[image]

As a beginner in the field, I have only encountered 1D values of `y`, e.g. cost of a particular thing based on some dependent parameters. But if `y` is a 2D value, like a coordinate of a point, how do I calculate it ?

The exact problem is that I have a set of predicted points that have been predicted by a linear model - `A = [(1,2), (2,3), (3,4)]` and I have a set of actual points - `B = [(1.1, 1.9),(2, 3.5),(3.4, 4.2)]`, and I want to see how my predictions `A` did in estimating `B`. Is there a way to calculate the R2 score in such a case ?